# Does hyphen need to be escaped in a regular expression?

Tags: regex, linux, grep

The following returns a bunch of results including those containing "->emit"

```
grep -rnw '/var/www/react' -e ">emit"
```

But the following returns no results

```
grep -rnw '/var/www/react' -e "->emit"
```

Why?

Comment: the hyphen doesn't need to be escaped except in a character class *(since it defines a range)*. Note that there are several characters that look like the "ascii hyphen" in the unicode table.

Comment: What does your file have?  Can you add an example pattern from your file to your question above?

Comment: @codeforester  Among many, one is `/var/www/react/vendor/evenement/evenement/tests/Evenement/Tests/EventEmitterTest.php:232:        $this->emitter->emit('bar');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to drop the `-w` option. It says to treat the expression as a whole word. A `word` must be bounded by non-word characters, i.e. it must only be surrounded by characters other than `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

`emit` would match `emit`, `_emit`, or `->emit`, but not `remit`.

I'm guessing that your `->emit` is trying to match something like `a->emit`, but can't because `a` is a `word` character.

Answer (score 1):

Its a whole word match, Please find 
[grep Documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Matching-Control)

> Suppose I want to search for a whole word, not a part of a word?
>
> grep -w 'hello' *
>
> searches only for instances of ‘hello’ that are entire words; it does
>   not match ‘Othello’. For more control, use ‘\<’ and ‘\>’ to match the
>   start and end of words. For example:
>
> grep 'hello\>' *
>
> **searches only for words ending in ‘hello’, so it matches the word**
>   ‘Othello’.